# Adding customized product in Woocommerce programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a setup much like [Woocommerce product designer](http://demos.orionorigin.com/wpc_demo/) is built.

**Example:** Product "cup-design" is added with custom fields, in this case a user generated image, to the cart. When next "cup-design" is added **it should appear as a new item in the cart**.
This is where I'm stuck.

---

There is no problem adding the product with custom a field

```
  $variation_id = $_POST['id']; // Product ID
  $image = $_POST['image']; // User generated image
  $variable_product = wc_get_product($variation_id);
  $variation = array();

  if ($variable_product->product_type == "simple") {
      $product_id = $variation_id;
  } else {
      $variation = $variable_product->variation_data;
      $product_id = $variable_product->parent->id;
  }

  $new_cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $image);
```

But I need them to be added individually since I'ts the same product being added over and over again.

Comment: As long as the `$cart_item_data` data (5th param of `add_to_cart()` method; you're calling it `$image`) is difference then the item won't be detected as a duplicate of one of the items in the cart.

Comment: @helgatheviking The content of `$image` is always unique. Do you have a working example?